# Let $f (z) $ be an entire function such that $|f (z)|≤K|z|$, $∀z∈\mathbb{C}$, for some $K>0$. If $f (1) =i$, then$f (i) $ is

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f (z) $ be an entire function such that $|f (z)|≤K|z|$, $∀z∈\mathbb{C}$, for some $K>0$. If $f (1) =i$, the value of $f (i) $ is
(A)  $ 1 $
(B)$-1$
(C) $i$
(D) $-i$

how can I able to solve this problem?totally stuck.

Answer (score 4):

The function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}z$ is also entire (why is there no problem at $z=0$?) and bounded by $K$, hence constant. We conclude that $f(z)=iz$.